# How to declare list type variable and pass it into model in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

My query is to get names of employees whose Date of Birth is current date.
My LINQ query in controller is:

```
         EmployeeModel objUser = new EmployeeModel();
         var users = dbContext.EmployeeProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.DOB == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM")).UserName; 
         objUser.Users = users.ToList();
         return View(objUser);
```

How to declare **Users** in the model?

Please note: My View is strongly-typed view (of EmployeeModel)

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` returns a single object (or `null`), not a collection - you want a `.Where()` and a `.Select()`

Comment: Ok thanks Stephen. Now how to declare it in model?

Comment: Do you want a single name which is what your query is returning `(string Users`) or a collection of names (`IEnumerable<string> Users`)

Comment: I will require list of users. There could be more than one. What changes are required in the controller, and how to declare that list type in the model for this purpose?

Comment: `dbContext.EmployeeProfiles.Where(x => x.DOB == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM")).Select(x => x.UserName)` and `public IEnumerable<string> Users { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `var users` is of type `EmployeeProfile` since you are querying `dbContext.EmployeeProfiles.....` :

```
public class EmployeeModel
  {
    public List<EmployeeProfile> Users { get; set; }

    //...some other properties here....
  }
```

this answer is as straightforward as I could make it but I would actually recommend using `ICollection<EmployeeProfile>` instead of `List<EmployeeProfile>`

Answer (score -1):

At the top of the view ->

```
@model EmployeeModel
{
   var Users=Model.Users;
}
```

Comment: But how to declare Users in the EmployeeModel?

Comment: So in EmployeeModel there is no field named Users??

Comment: Yes. I do not know how to declare a list type for this purpose in the model.

Comment: if UserName is type of string then you can declare it in EmployeeModel->
public class EmployeeModel{
....
public List<string> Users {get; set;}
.....
}